# How to include glm in opencl application?

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm tyring to include glm as a data structure types for vec3,..etc but I can't include it, it always complain about other headers like cmath.h is not found

```
err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, "-I C:\\Users\\xgame\\Desktop\\test\\opencl_raster\\external\\include\\glm", NULL, NULL);
```

In kernel:

```
#include "glm.hpp"



Could not open file: C:\Users\xgame\AppData\Local\Temp\dep-70203f.d
In file included from <kernel>:1:
In file included from C:\Users\xgame\Desktop\test\opencl_raster\external\include\glm\glm.hpp:81:
C:\Users\xgame\Desktop\test\opencl_raster\external\include\glm/detail/_fixes.hpp:33:10: fatal error: 'cmath' file not found
#include <cmath>
         ^
```

Comment: Open cl kernels aren't c++, you can't use c++ libraries

Comment: @AlanBirtles Is there a work around ?

Comment: The latest open cl compilers do seem to support c++, you'll need to precompile your code though, it doesn't look like many drivers have implemented the c++extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `#include "some_header.h"` works in OpenCL C, you cannot include C++ headers. OpenCL C is based on C99, not C++; it does not support a lot of C++ functionality like classes.

The good news is: OpenCL C already has cmath-like functionality and vector types built-in, for example the `float3` vector type. No need to include headers for that or write it yourself.

Available math functionality and vector types are listed in this handy [Reference Card](https://www.khronos.org/files/opencl30-reference-guide.pdf).